# Using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect with multiple widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicseffect

I want to set a shadow on several widgets using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect and I am wondering if there is a better way to do so without having to write the same code over and over again for every instance where I want to use it like in my example below. Is it possible to create a class or something to call so that I just have to set `setGraphicsEffect()` on the widgets? I have tried to create a few classes for it but I was still only able to get them to create one shadow.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QPushButton, QApplication, QComboBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(5)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(3)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(3)

        self.shadow2 = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        self.shadow2.setBlurRadius(5)
        self.shadow2.setXOffset(3)
        self.shadow2.setYOffset(3)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.btn.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow2)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect) states that the same QGraphicsEffect can not be shared by other widgets:

> If effect is the installed effect on a different widget, [`setGraphicsEffect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect) will remove the effect from the widget and install it on this widget.

So you will have to create a [`QGraphicsEffect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html) for each widget, but if you do not want to write a lot of code and want to apply effects with similar characteristics you could iterate through the widgets and for that you can use [`findChildren(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QPushButton, QApplication, QComboBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.combo = QComboBox()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        for child in self.findChildren(QWidget):
            shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=5, xOffset=3, yOffset=3)
            child.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This example doesn't work, because you need give a parent to QGraphicsDropShadowEffect constructor.   You need to add "parent=child,"ast least with PySide2

Answer (score 0):

Children inherit the effect, so all you needed to do is set it on the parent

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QPushButton, QApplication, QComboBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(16)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(8)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(8)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.combo = QComboBox()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing the same issue, I have found a working solution(at least working). It's not the best solution in my opinion, but it's a simple approach and gives the desired behavior. You just should add every QLabel in a list and run for loop through the list and apply the shadow effect on every iteration.

```
# Import PyQt5 Engine 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, 
                             QWidget, 
                             QPushButton, 
                             QLabel, 
                             QLineEdit, 
                             QMessageBox, 
                             QPlainTextEdit, 
                             QHBoxLayout, 
                             QVBoxLayout,
                             QGraphicsDropShadowEffect) 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main")
        self.setGeometry(650, 300, 100, 50)
        self.setMaximumWidth(400)
        self.setMaximumHeight(300)
        
        qlabels = []
        
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addSpacing(2)
        
        self.line_one = QLabel()
        self.line_one.setText("Line One")
        self.line_one.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        qlabels.append(self.line_one)
        
        self.line_two = QLabel()
        self.line_two.setText("Line Two")
        self.line_two.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        qlabels.append(self.line_two)
        
        for i in range(len(qlabels)):
            shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
            shadow.setOffset(2, 1)
            qlabels[i].setGraphicsEffect(shadow)
        
        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.line_one)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.line_two)
        
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.show()


        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main()
window.show()
app.exec()
```